# Bibtex doesnt seem to recognize my citations

Tags: bibtex

My laptop broke and I had to buy a new one. I pulled my senior thesis from github after reinstalling everything and now bibtex does not seem to recognize my citations.

I have a jupyter notebook with citations in the form of "cite data-cite="CitationName"></cite" (with the necessary < and > brackets)
I run the following prompts to convert the notebook to pdf with citations.

```
jupyter nbconvert MyFile.ipynb --to latex --no-input --template citations.tplx 
pdflatex MyFile.tex 
bibtex MyFile.aux 
pdflatex MyFile.tex 
pdflatex MyFile.tex 
pdflatex MyFile.tex
```

On my last laptop this worked fine, but now the citations are [?] and there is no reference page at the end.

my tplx file looks like this

```
((*- extends 'article.tplx' -*))

((* block author *))
\author{NAME}
((* endblock author *))

((* block title *))
\title{TITLE}
((* endblock title *))

((* block bibliography *))
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Fraud}
((* endblock bibliography *))
```

and my bib file is named Fraud.bib, I've run out of ideas. When I run the bibtex line I get:

```
The top-level auxiliary file: MyFile.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file MyFile.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file MyFile.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
```

when i run pdflatex I get a bunch of undefined warnings.

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `biau2016random' on page 3 undefined on input line 518.



LaTeX Warning: Citation `belgiu2016random' on page 3 undefined on input line 53
3.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `breiman2001random' on page 3 undefined on input line 5
77.
```

They all exist in the .bib file. I've tried reinstalling miktex and updating it. I've tried other jupyter files to check for corruption and this still happpens.

What could possibly be going wrong?

Edit: Tex file example: https://pastebin.com/N8BKZWd1

bib file:

```
  title={Random forest in remote sensing: A review of applications and future directions},
  author={Belgiu, Mariana and Dr{\u{a}}gu{\c{t}}, Lucian},
  journal={ISPRS journal of photogrammetry and remote sensing},
  volume={114},
  pages={24--31},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{diaz2006gene,
  title={Gene selection and classification of microarray data using random forest},
  author={D{\'\i}az-Uriarte, Ram{\'o}n and De Andres, Sara Alvarez},
  journal={BMC bioinformatics},
  volume={7},
  number={1},
  pages={1--13},
  year={2006},
  publisher={BioMed Central}
}
@article{biau2016random,
  title={A random forest guided tour},
  author={Biau, G{\'e}rard and Scornet, Erwan},
  journal={Test},
  volume={25},
  number={2},
  pages={197--227},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{breiman2001random,
  title={Random forests},
  author={Breiman, Leo},
  journal={Machine learning},
  volume={45},
  number={1},
  pages={5--32},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{bhowmik2011detecting,
  title={Detecting auto insurance fraud by data mining techniques},
  author={Bhowmik, Rekha},
  journal={Journal of Emerging Trends in Computing and Information Sciences},
  volume={2},
  number={4},
  pages={156--162},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Citeseer}
}
@article{ngai2011application,
  title={The application of data mining techniques in financial fraud detection: A classification framework and an academic review of literature},
  author={Ngai, Eric WT and Hu, Yong and Wong, Yiu Hing and Chen, Yijun and Sun, Xin},
  journal={Decision support systems},
  volume={50},
  number={3},
  pages={559--569},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{hall1994logistic,
  title={Logistic regression—explanation and use},
  author={Hall, GH and Round, AP},
  journal={Journal of the Royal College of Physicians of London},
  volume={28},
  number={3},
  pages={242},
  year={1994},
  publisher={Royal College of Physicians}
}
@inproceedings{liu2008isolation,
  title={Isolation forest},
  author={Liu, Fei Tony and Ting, Kai Ming and Zhou, Zhi-Hua},
  booktitle={2008 eighth ieee international conference on data mining},
  pages={413--422},
  year={2008},
  organization={IEEE}
}
@article{jakkula2006tutorial,
  title={Tutorial on support vector machine (svm)},
  author={Jakkula, Vikramaditya},
  journal={School of EECS, Washington State University},
  volume={37},
  year={2006}
}
@article{tong2001support,
  title={Support vector machine active learning with applications to text classification},
  author={Tong, Simon and Koller, Daphne},
  journal={Journal of machine learning research},
  volume={2},
  number={Nov},
  pages={45--66},
  year={2001}
}
@inproceedings{li2010explanation,
  title={The explanation of support vector machine in customer churn prediction},
  author={Li, Yi and Xia, Guo-en},
  booktitle={2010 International Conference on E-Product E-Service and E-Entertainment},
  pages={1--4},
  year={2010},
  organization={IEEE}
}
@article{alghushairy2021review,
  title={A Review of Local Outlier Factor Algorithms for Outlier Detection in Big Data Streams},
  author={Alghushairy, Omar and Alsini, Raed and Soule, Terence and Ma, Xiaogang},
  journal={Big Data and Cognitive Computing},
  volume={5},
  number={1},
  pages={1},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute}
}
@inproceedings{batista2009k,
  title={How k-nearest neighbor parameters affect its performance},
  author={Batista, GEAPA and Silva, Diego Furtado and others},
  booktitle={Argentine symposium on artificial intelligence},
  pages={1--12},
  year={2009},
  organization={Citeseer}
}
@misc{morde_2019, 
 title={XGBoost Algorithm: Long May She Reign!},
 url= {https://towardsdatascience.com},
 journal={Towards Data Science},
 publisher={Towards Data Science},
 author={Morde, Vishal},
 year={2019}, 
month={Apr}
} 
@inproceedings{chen2016xgboost,
  title={Xgboost: A scalable tree boosting system},
  author={Chen, Tianqi and Guestrin, Carlos},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 22nd acm sigkdd international conference on knowledge discovery and data mining},
  pages={785--794},
  year={2016}
}
@article{wang2019xgboost,
  title={A XGBoost risk model via feature selection and Bayesian hyper-parameter optimization},
  author={Wang, Yan and Ni, Xuelei Sherry},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1901.08433},
  year={2019}
}
```

Comment: Please show the generated tex file (perhaps make a new minimal project, cite something, if it has the same problem show us the tex code and the actual bib entries.

Comment: @daleif I've updated the post. I tried to put the bib on pastebin as well but their filters thought I was posting something inappropriate. Sorry for that.

Comment: Please put everything here (why I asked for a small example), external links rot over time and thus your question will become useless in the future